# In R, how do I compute mean and standard error of a subset of data, grouped by multiple columns, and output this into a new data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, mean, standard-error

I have a dataset (named 'gala') that has the columns "Day", "Tree", "Trt", and "LogColumn". The data was collected over time, so each numbered tree is the same tree for each treatment is the same across all days. The tree numbers are repeated for each treatment (e.g. there is a tree "1" for multiple treatments).

I would like to compute the mean and standard error for the 'LogColumn' column, for each tree per each treatment per each day (e.g. I will have a mean + standard error for day 1, tree one, treatment x, etc.), and output the mean and standard error results into a new data frame that also includes the original day, Tree, Trt values.

I have been unsuccessfully trying to make a Frankenstein of codes from other Stack Overflow answers, but I cannot seem to find one that has all the components at once. If I missed this, I am sorry, and please let me know with a link to this answer. I am new to coding, and R, and do not understand well how other codes not directly relating to what I would like to do can be applied.

At this point, I have this, but do not know if it is anywhere near correct (I am also currently getting the error message "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"):
`TreeAverages <- data.table[, MeanLog=mean(gala$LogColumn), se=std.error(gala$LogColumn), by=c("Day","Tree","Trt")]`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using data.table, remember to convert gala into a data.table object first.

```
gala = data.table(gala)

gala_output = gala[, .("MeanLog" = mean(LogColumn), 
         "std" = std.error(LogColumn)), 
     by = c("Day", "Tree", "Trt")]
```

You were really close, but `data.table` works like `dplyr` does, so it already knows variable names. You don't need to specify `gala$LogColumn` throughout, just do it by name.

`.()` is just a shorthand for `list()`, so I'm specifying that data.table should return the columns `MeanLog` and `std` grouped by `Day`, `Tree`, and `Trt`.

Comment: I get the error ```could not find function "std.error"```

Comment: figured it out - it requires ```library(plotrix)```

Answer (score 7):

Using base R `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(LogColumn ~ Day + Tree + Trt, data = gala, 
          FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), se = std.error(x)))
```

Comment: Great solution. I don't think std.error() is a base function. For those who want to use the above just: install.packages"plotrix") then library(plotrix) and the above should work well!

Answer (score 4):

Using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- gala %>% 
  group_by(Day, Tree, Trt) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(LogColumn),
            std = sd(LogColumn))
```